# How do i run my python script in a remote server using Server X in Mobaxterm

Tags: ssh, xserver, mobaxterm

I am connected to a remote server through a SSH session in Mobaxterm. While console programs run just fine, i am now trying to run a graphic program. Through some digging, i found out about X Server (X11) and i wanna try it out but i can't see to make it work.

I activated the X server functionality with top right button on Mobaxterm and then run my program but it fails with this error:

`_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:11.0"`

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider posting questions like this on [su]. And if there's any more to that error message that what you've quoted, you should include it in the question. Because the message that you quoted is pretty vague.